# Spotfire 6.0.2.14 How to Import Page from one report to another?

Tags: spotfire

I have two .dxp reports. How can I import whole pages from one report to another?

Or maybe there is a way to merge / union these reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this feature does not exist in Spotfire 6.0.x. you'll need to upgrade to Spotfire 6.5+.